# How to drop App table with Django and Postgres

Tags: django, postgresql

I'm trying to drop a single table from my App's database in a Django project. When I enter the database shell using `manage.py dbshell`, I try to execute `DROP TABLE mytable;` and get `ERROR:  table "mytable" does not exist` I think the cause of this stems from the database thinking I'm in my project directory instead of my app directory but I don't know how to change that.

This is what the shell looks like after I type `./manage.py dbshell`:

`myproject=# DROP TABLE mytable;
ERROR:  table "mytable" does not exist`

I think instead of `myproject=#` it should say something like `myapp=#` or `myproject/myapp=#` but I do not know how to accomplish this.

Comment: Why don't you use postgresql console ?

Comment: remove corresponding models from `models.py` and do `migration`

Comment: Removing the model from model.py will force me to also remove any (or most) references to that model in my code before I can see if it works. It'll be tedious but I may do that as a last resort.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

After accessing your local db via: `sudo -i -u postgres`

Or `python manage.py dbshell`

Try typing `\l` to see what databases do you actually have

Then `\dt` to see a list of relations

And then `DROP TABLE some_table;`

Comment: Thank you for your response. I after typing in those commands, the only relevant database that shows up is in fact the MyProject database. Am I only able to delete this?

Comment: Well there must be several databases including the database of your django project, others are a standard postgresql databases, you might delete them as well, but there is no point in doing so

Comment: Let me know if there are some other issues

Comment: You were correct! I was looking at the wrong layout. At the bottom of the `\dt` output was the myapp_mytable name that I needed to type in to delete it. I was simply typing the incorrect name. Thank you very much for your help! I was stuck on this for awhile.

Comment: thanks :)
`DROP TABLE public."some_table";`
worked for me.

Comment: You are welcome